# Read other process' memory from webassembly with user's consent

Tags: blazor-webassembly, webassembly

Is it possible for code running in webassembly (e.g. Blazor) to read memory of another process (like we can do from regular code) if the user wants this and is willing to configure his browser accordingly?

Comment: Do you mean "from" instead of "form" in the title?

Comment: No.  Think of the security implications if it were possible!